# Access VBA: how to subscribe to a the change of a control/field happened from other vba code and not from user interaction

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm in a weird situation.
I have a form with a subform.
When a value in the subform changes, in the after update I call

```
If Not IsNull(Me.Parent) Then
   Me.Parent.ParentField.Value = Me.SubformField.Value
End If
```

In the parent form I want the change in `ParentField` to trigger another event.
Too bad that changing programmatically doesn't trigger either the `AfterUpdate` nor the `onChange` event.

Since the same subform is used in more parent forms I can't call directly the method that is called on the afterUpdate

Is there something else I can "subscribe" to?

Comment: Based on experience with Excel userforms (not sure if this translates to Access; hence not adding as an answer). Possibly create a class with the subform. When the value changes raise a custom event. On the parent forms, adding an instance of the subform class withevents should allow custom code to be added in the Parent's code-behind under the custom event; similar to adding code for a dropdop/textbox change, button click, etc.

Comment: Your answere seemed exactly what I wanted, but unfortunately I didn't quite get how to implement it.
I went with a "stupid" solution that checks if the parent is the one having the correct function and called the function only if there's a match. Not ideal but the quickest solution given my time restraints.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll add an answer with more detail, and a mock-up for anyone who might be working on this in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in Excel, this can be accomplished by adding a custom event to the sub userform, then adding the subuserform as an object in the parent userforms.

I created a mock-up, shown below (the command button on the Parent Userform is primarily to hold the initial focus, as in this mock-up the sub form opens when the text box is entered):

[image: Sub and Parent Userforms]

```
'SubUserForm code
Option Explicit
'Custom Events don't have to pass values, or can pass multiple values as desired
Public Event FormChange(newValue As Variant)

Private Sub TextBoxS_Change()
    'If I wanted the event to raise for various control changes,
    '    I could add it to multiple Change Events.
    RaiseEvent FormChange(TextBoxS.Value)

    'Or I could instead call a private sub such as
    '        ConditionalEvent(TextBoxS.Value)
    '    with the logic for checking if the event should
    '    be raised; especially helpful if
    '    logic depends on multiple changes or conditions
End Sub

Private Sub ConditionalEvent(vNew As Variant)
    If True Then 'More complicated checks, maybe changed private variables, etc.
        RaiseEvent FormChange(vNew)
    End If
End Sub

'This is to prevent the parent losing refernce to the sub form.
'The parent should be the one that creates an instance of this form,
'   as well as be the one to delete it.
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    Cancel = True
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

---

```
'Parent UserForm code
Option Explicit
'The private instance of the subform needs to be of the
'    baseform itself, not a generic object or userform.
'    Otherwise the custom event won't carry through.
'    However, this also means that the only events carried through
'    will be the custom ones (at least as far as I could tell)
Private WithEvents subForm As SubUserForm

'This is the custom event from the subform
Private Sub subForm_FormChange(newValue As Variant)
    TextBoxP.Value = newValue
End Sub

'This is important. The default value of subform is Nothing,
'    so initialization is required.
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set subForm = New SubUserForm
End Sub

'This sub is the mock-up logic and call to show the sub form for testing.
'It is not required for using custom events.
Private Sub TextBoxP_Enter()
    subForm.Show
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    'Terminates the subform on parent closure
    Set subForm = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

For testing, I used the code below to show the parent userform. Please note I also changed the names of the TextBoxes and userforms like so:

- Subform: `SubUserForm`, `TextBoxS`
- ParentForm: `ParentUserFrom`, `TextBoxP`

If any one wants to use the code mock-up, after creating the userforms, they will either need to change the names of the textboxes and userforms, or their references in the code.

```
'In a generic module
Option Explicit

' Used to open the parent form for testing
Sub test()
    ' Using a with statement allows using a new instance of the form
    '    (instead of the "free instance" automatically provided)
    '    without having to assign the new instance to a variable to
    '    use, and then having to assign to variable to Nothing
    With New ParentUserForm
        .Show
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, a controls events don’t fire when changed by VBA. This makes sense, since a lot of events could occur for that control, and thus determining when and when not to have all those events run would be a nightmare.

However, you can most certainly call code and execute code in the parent form and have it run.

So if a button or some event code runs for a given control, simply have that event code call a public sub in the parent form.

So button click, or after update could go:

```
Call MySub
```

MySub is simply a public sub that the button or event code calls in the main form.

Now, in the sub form, you can go:

```
Me.Parent.ParentField.Value = me.SomeField

Call me.Parent.MySub()
```

And I suppose you could also use a Function, and go:

```
My.Parent.MyFunctionToRun()
```

So setup a common routine (sub or function) in the parent form that the event code (or button) calls. And then simply call that same routine as per above in the sub form.

Comment: I feared that there was no event fired when changing code from VBA.
I wanted to avoid directly calling a parent function since I have more parents using the same subform, and not all of the parents have that method.

I ended up just running a check on the parent `FormName` property and called the method only if it matches the right name.
I wanted the subform to be ignorant of the parent, but I guess it'impossible.